# AWS MQ Maintenance window

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mq

I use the AWS MQ service to allow my applications to communicate with each other.

Unfortunately, my broker restarts almost every Tuesday even though I have disabled the option for AWS to automatically update my broker.

Do you have any ideas?

**Broker instance type**: mq.t2.micro

**Deployment mode**:
Single-instance broker

**Storage type**: 
Amazon Elastic File System

**Broker engine**:
ActiveMQ

**Broker engine version**:
5.15.9
[image]

Comment: The entire instance restarts ?  Does it occur at the same time every week ?

Comment: @AdiDembak Yes the entire instance restarts and it occur at the same time ! You can see, i update my post with the "maintenance" section on my MQ Panel